# Broke Ubuntu 12.04 either with Screencloud or Ubuntu Tweak

Tags: 12.04

Earlier today I installed the Screen Shot app "Screencloud" and after the installation Firefox was having problems. I didn't think much about it, just closed Firefox, then proceeded to change the toolbar opacity on Ubuntu Tweak.

After restarting my system, hoping it would fix Firefox (because, you know, restarting fixes everything ;) ) I am able to go to the Log In Screen, type in my password, but then I get 3 errors regarding the Screencloud Ubuntu One, Imgur, and Dropbox plugins. After clicking the "Okay" on all three errors, all I see is my wallpaper. I am not able to access the terminal VIA Ctrl>Alt>T, but I am able to log out VIA Ctrl>Alt>Delete.

I have tried all desktop environments I have installed (that, except for Unity 2D, has to do with Cairo Dock.)

I hope I have provided enough information. If you need more, please ask. Please help! I would like to not have to re-install Ubuntu.

Other info:

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

I also have a Ubuntu 12.10 Live USB, but Ubuntu 12.10 hasn't run very well on any of my computers.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to change settings that will cause Unity to not run correctly, however the settings in Ubuntu Tweak have been select to avoid this.  You could try resetting Unity in any case:

```
unity --reset
```

You should be able to get to a console to do this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>

You can also remove screencloud with the command line.

```
sudo apt-get remove screencloud
```

however no-one else seems to have reported Unity conflict problems with it.

Comment: I installed it from Software center

Comment: When I typed `unity --reset` everything was working fine, until it got to something about re-setting the Screenshot hot-key's. So, I'm guessing I somehow screwed up my hot-key's. Now it is stuck at that command. What would you suggest I do?

Comment: Maybe try rebooting at this point.  Open another console with Ctrl-Alt-F2 and type "sudo reboot"

Comment: I rebooted, then when it booted up again, there was no change. I un-installed Screencloud with `sudo apt-get remove screencloud` then tried re-setting again, but that didn't change. I am currently installing gnome-shell, so that I am at least abe to use Ubuntu until I can find a solution t this problem. Would you suggest un-installing then re-installing Unity?

Comment: I'm not sure re-installing unity will fix the problem.  Maybe try a re-install first.

Comment: Try re-installing Unity? Or a complete Ubuntu re-install?

Comment: I meant re-install unity - "sudo apt-get --reinstall unity", but as I said, I'm not convinced it's going to solve your problem.

Comment: Okay. I'll try that, and if it doesn't work I wanted to re-try Ubuntu 12.10 anyway xD

Comment: If you're going to re-install, set up two root partitions of about 25Gb each - one for 12.04 LTS and the other for 12.10.  Set up a partition for swap, and a partition that takes up the rest of the drive for /home.  That way, re-installation is a breeze since /home never gets formatted again, and you always have one working system no matter what you do to the other one.

Comment: Can you dual boot with three OS's? (I also have Windows 7)

Comment: 3, or 53.  It probably starts getting silly around 6 or 7 though.  I have found 4 Ubuntu installations starts to get a bit difficult.  On an MBR partition the maximum number of Primary partitions is 4, so you should make an extended partition after your windows partition and put all of the other partition in that one.  Search on here and google and you will get plenty of ideas for designing partition layouts.